# How can I implement a timer in c for a game?

Tags: c, timer, operating-system, alarm

I'm making connect 4 in C and I want to implement a function that obliges a player to do his move in 30 seconds. 5 seconds before the time runs out I want to notify to the player that time is running out. How can I do that?
This is not the entire code, i want to understand only how to do that. Thank you!

```
while(1){

        alarm(30);
       // Print game field
        printMat();

        do{
            printf("\nMake a move:");

            scanf("%d", &move);

        }while(isNotValid(move));

        alarm(0);                      

        //
        move(move, player_symbol);

        // Swap turn to the other player
        SwapPlayer();
    }
```

Comment: With a single thread: not by using any blocking input like `scanf`. You'd need a non-blocking input and check the timing while waiting for events from the input. You'll also need a timer with better resolution than 1 second, because you can be 1 second out.

Comment: Timers are OS-specific. You should either use OS-specific timers API or use cross-platform library which already implemets it for you. E.g. [libuv](https://libuv.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick proof of concept (on Linux):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TIMEOUT 30

void alarm_handler(int signal) {}

int move() {
    alarm(TIMEOUT);
    printf("Make a move: ");
    int move;
    if(scanf("%d", &move) != 1) {
        printf("\n");
        if(feof(stdin))
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        move = -1;
    }
    alarm(0);
    return move;
}

int main(void) {
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &(const struct sigaction) {.sa_handler = alarm_handler}, NULL);
    for(;;)
        printf("%d\n", move());
}
```

and example output:

```
$ ./a.out 
Make a move: (wait 30 seconds here)
-1
Make a move: 3
3
```